# Possible to load Shiny UI elements from Github?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinyjs

Is it possible to create a "standard" top-level menu using navbarMenu, which can be stored in GitHub and then linked via UI in shiny apps?

Example: We have a standard menu that we want to use on multiple apps, instead of rewriting the same piece of code, is it possible to move some parts of the UI to GitHub to reuse? Such as the navbarMenu items given below:

```
navbarMenu(actionButton("A", "Report A")
                      ),
navbarMenu(actionButton("B", "Report B")
                      ),
navbarMenu(actionButton("C", "Report C")
                      )
```